# Section Symbol and Number

Tags: sectioning

How does one get the symbol `\S` to appear before a number in `\section{}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the formatting of section headings easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```