# How to add section characters in LyX?

Tags: sectioning, lyx

I want my work to have those curly section marks (`\S`) at the beginning of every section. I came across this question: [Section Symbol and Number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14623/section-symbol-and-number), which does answer the question in LaTeX but I was wondering if there's an even simpler answers for those who use LyX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs considering that this is LyX, I don't know if `\documentclass{...}` is in order here... @Donjim, I'm not at a computer with LyX at the moment, but you should be able to copy those two lines in the linked question (`\usepackage` and `\titleformat`) into your preamble (Layout -> Document -> Preamble) and be good to go.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks! That's much better than adding a LaTeX box at the beginning of the document. I feel very spoiled in asking this, but I'd be honest and say I wondered if there was something more along the lines of a document class suited for this?
If no one answers in a couple of days I'll accept your answer of course, since it is just as good.

Comment: @Donjim, it could easily be implemented as such, but I'd caution against it. Doing so could introduce a pattern that will get out of hand *very* quickly, producing new document classes for an arbitrary number of styles, remembering to texhash each time a new one is made, etc.  would you rather find a way to auto-populate your preamble?

Comment: @Donjim you could create a LyX module which does this, if you liked that better. That way you could go to Document Settings > Modules and then add it. This seems unnecessary to me for just one line of preamble code though. But if you are interested, read the documentation in Help > Customization.

Comment: @scottkosty thanks! I'll check it out. 
To SeanAllred yeah, some tool to auto populate the preamble could be nice. I mean, as far as I know, LyX's intention is to make as much of the format and such behind the scenes for whomever wants to simply deal with the content. So I would say the LaTeX preamble is quite the opposite of this approach, in a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, @SeanAllred answered the question in the comments section. Since it bugs me to leave a question unanswered I thought I'd just add it as an answer. (I'm not sure if that agrees with stack exchange etiquette, guess I'm about to find out)

The simple answer would be to copy these lines

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}
```

to the LaTeX preamble box under Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble. I have tried it and it works well!

A different approach suggested by @scottkosty is to create a LyX module for this. I haven't tried it, so I wouldn't know.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the normal thing to do is to write a comment asking the commenter to post a "proper" answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! I'll remember it next time.