# Put the § symbol before each section number

Tags: titlesec, cleveref

I'm writing a document (`article` class). I'm using the clever reference package to crossreference sections, and I have modified the references so the `\cref{label}` produces, for example if it's section 2, the symbol `§2`. I have also modified the (sub)section and part title formats via titlesec, all with the following code:

```
\crefname{section}{§}{§§}
\Crefname{section}{§}{§§}
\crefname{part}{§}{§§}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large §\scshape\centering}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large §\scshape}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
   {\LARGE §\scshape\centering}
   {\thepart}
   {0em}
   {}
```

The last thing I would like to do is to make it print the symbol § before the number of the section in each section. I have tried doing like above, just putting it in the second {} of the titleformat command for each of them, but that obviously writes it before the title of the section, leaving something like this:

```
3.1 §This is a section.
```

Plus Auctex returns an error when compiling with Latex (`Error ocurred after las TeX file closed`) although it produces the correct dvi file.

How could I correctly achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give a compilable MWE which shows your documentclass and a sample section. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), not just code snippets. It's unproductive having to guess, for instance, which package needs to be loaded in order to enable the macro `\titleformat`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127623 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14623

Comment: The usage of the paragraph sign hints that your document might have a legal background. There are some packages for legal documents, so if you tell us, what kind of document it is and in which level of sections you'd like to have a §.

Comment: @KeksDose Nope, it's a mathematical document. Just sections and subsections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, solved it, didn't know how to use properly the `\titlesec` command. I used

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\scshape\centering}{§\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\scshape}{§\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Without the * for full formatting.

Sorry for asking and answering myself.

EDIT:
Just for future reference, in case someone runs into this:
In the previous snippet, the four `{}` parts at the right of the `[]` are: text-style, then what's displayed before the (sub)section title, then the space between enumeration and title, and then something to separate enumeration and title. In this case `\thesection` outputs the number of the section, `1em` is the space between the number of the section and the title, and there's symbolic separation between them.

The `[]` can be `hang` in which case al of it is displayed in a single line, or `display`, in which case there is a line for the enumeration, then a line with the separation (fourth `{}`), and then the title.

Comment: Well, then accept your own answer to avoid that this question will be regarded as unanswered by the system.

Comment: You *can* answer your own questions, but I think the system will prevent you from accepting your own answer for a while (to give others the chance to respond as well). But yes, the system allows you to answer your own questions, no need to apologise.

Comment: @KeksDose It doesn't allow me to do so until 2 days have passed...